# How can I set a column value to a GUID and what data type should I use?

Tags: sql-server

I would like to have a column in one of my tables set to a GUID value. Can someone tell me how I can do this by default and also what datatype and size I should use for this. Is there a special guid datatype or should I use a char or varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUID are the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type, example below of a table with one

```
CREATE TABLE MyUniqueTable
   (UniqueColumn   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      DEFAULT NEWID(),
   Characters      VARCHAR(10) )
GO
```

You use NEWID() and SQL will generate a new guid for you.

Comment: When I do a select and return data from this column will it convert and go into a normal string in my C# code ?  Also are there efficiencies with storing it as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER instead of putting it into a char?

Comment: You can convert it to a string when you read it from the database or use a C# guid data type.

Comment: So when it is in the database and I do a select * do I see it like a string? thanks?

Comment: It will return a datatype of uniqueidentifier in a select * statement. You can convert it to a char in your select with a statement such as "SELECT CONVERT(char(255), @myid) AS 'char';" where @myid is your guid or you can convert it to a string when you get it in your c# code.

Comment: What if I want to store it as a char in the database? Would that not be easier? I am using EF6 and I am not sure how friendly that is with UNIQUEIDENTIFIERS.

Comment: If you store it as a char, you lose all the benefits of it being Unique. EF6 supports uniqueidentifiers. Use a data type of guid in your model class.